# Error while trying to commit a file through TortoiseSVN

Tags: tortoisesvn

i setup a SVN server in ubuntu. I am able to checkout and commit changes to my files using the terminal. I want to access my repositories in windows and so i setup TortoiseSVN. I was able to checkout the contents of my repository to a folder but i am not able to commit or import as i get the error

> "Commit Failed, attempt to write a readonly database"

. I tried to clear the cache to see if i can enter username and password but there is no authenticated data. How can i fix this? Is there any way to set the user as which tortoiseSVN makes the commits? Thanks.

Not sure if this is required but here is a link to my repository: http://46.137.254.155/usr/local/svn/

Comment: http or svn+ssh used? chmod repodir or chown for getting +w rights

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the file `/svn/repopath/db/rep-cache.db` has write permissions for the user subversion uses.

More info here: http://www.gsdesign.ro/blog/error-svn-attempt-to-write-a-readonly-database-commit-failed/